# AWS EC2: Associte Elastic IP to my domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a AWS elastic IP adress. How can I associte my my domain name `example.com` with the elastic IP so that i can we can access it from anywhere ?

OR is there other way to associate my domain `example.com` to my aws instance ?

I went through internet but not found a soluion. I was trying `AWS S3` [follwing this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html) but I am not getting options as described in this document

Comment: Have you created an A record in your DNS yet?

Comment: yes in A record i added public ip

Comment: An Elastic IP mapped to an EC2 instance is no different (from a DNS standpoint) than a VPS or Dedicated Server. Have you checked that your security groups allow public ("Anywhere") access?

Comment: if i access like `ipaddress:port` from browser it shows my web page but just `ipaddress` doesn't

Comment: Is it running on port 80?

Comment: no it running on `8080`

Comment: if i run `example.com:8080` it running but `example.com` not

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. The default HTTP port is 80, you will have to specify port 8080 unless you either put a reverse proxy or an Elastic Load Balance in front of it (either of these solutions can remap port 8080 to port 80. Is this your own application? If so, it may be easier to reconfigure it to run on port 80 instead.

Comment: can you tell me the steps

Comment: If it is your own application, I cannot. If you want a guide on how to setup an Elastic Load Balancer, I can write you up an answer. Let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62987/discussion-between-laiello-and-manish).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Amazon Route 53** to associate an **Elastic IP address** to an EC2 instance.

If you already have a Hosted Zone defined in Route 53:

- **Create Record Set**
- **Type:** A record
- **Value:** Enter the Elastic IP address

Entering the URL in a browser should then resolve to the Elastic IP address.

You can test this by doing a `ping` to the DNS name. The DNS name should resolve to the Elastic IP address.